# String equals not working correctly

Tags: java, equals, equality, java-6

This is my debugging code:

```
log.error(u.getName() + " - " + u.getName().length() + " - host_node" + " - " + u.equals("host_node"));
```

My log:

```
11:27:16 [main] ERROR com.google - host_node - 9 - host_node - false
```

Why it doesn't equal, I am even checking length, to see if first contains whitespaces. But it does not.

Comment: Are you overriding equals? Or perhaps you want u.getName().equals("host_node")

Comment: GAHHH JUST WAS TYPO. I wish I could delete this question. Most of answers are correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use following as I suspect `u` is not a `String`.

```
u.getName().equals("host_node")
```

or better you can use the following to get `false` if the name is `null`.

```
"host_node".equals(u.getName())
```

Comment: I will always go with second option. Safe check to save the code from most irritating NullPointerException. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should compare u.getName() with the text, thus:

```
u.getName().equals("host_node")
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 u.equals("host_node")
```

compares the string with the object `u`, not its name! i.e. it's calling `u.equals()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
u.equals()
```

is not what you wanted to compare.
Maybe you want the name of u?

`u.getName().equals()` would be a better choice then.

Anyhow, your Post lacks some information about u and other context to answer this properly.